# Create random images Corona SDK Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I need some help, I want to do 6 variables and in these six variables put random images, for example:

```
image = display.newImage("MyImage.png")
image2 = display.newIMage("MyImage2.png")

one = random(image,image2)
```

I can't use the function random in this case.

For this, I need help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array of images, then select the image randomly:

```
images = {
    display.newImage("MyImage.png"),
    display.newIMage("MyImage2.png"),
    ...
    display.newIMage("MyImage5.png")
}
randomImage = images[math.random(1,6)]
```

@krs added that you can also use a table of file names and instantiate only one of them:

```
local imageFiles = {"MyImage.png","MyImage2.png", ... "MyImage5.png"}
local imageFile = imageFiles[math.random(#images)]
randomImage = display.newImage(imageFile)
```

If you chagne the image often the first technique is better since you only instantiate once, but it depends on your use case.

Comment: Is good, thanks, i have another problem, How can I put the equal variable in two differents variables, for example:  I have 2 variables that these variables need to have 1 equal variable: one = 1 two = one three = one, I can´t do this ?

Comment: Please ask a separate question, easier for everyone to find, answer, etc.